# Exact String match works for grep 2.6.3 but not for grep 3.0

Tags: grep, cygwin

I am facing an issue on my windows machine with Cygwin in it.
On one of my machine grep exact string match using `$` works:

```
$ ipconfig /all | grep -A 1 'My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2$'
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ##-##-##-##-##
```

The `grep` version on this machine is:

```
$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.6.3
```

However the same does not work on my other machine having `grep 3.0`:

```
$ ipconfig /all | grep -A 1 'My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2$'
```

The `grep` version on this machine:

```
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.0
```

If I remove `$` from the above command I get the results, but I want the exact string match.
Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: I have already tried `grep -w`, `grep -o`, but could not get the expectced answer

Comment: My guess is you have trailing whitespaces. Does `ipconfig /all | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' | grep -A 1 'My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2$'` return the expected?

Comment: Yes it works. But is [[:space:]] version specific? Will it work throughout?
Currently it's working on both of my machines, but trying to make it work for others as well.

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya `[[:space:]]` is a standard regular expression matching a space, tab or other whitespace characters.  `[[:blank:]]` matches only tab and space.

Comment: That has more likely to do with how the CRLF line delimiter handling is done (`ipconfig` being not a Cygwin command, I'd expect it uses Windows line delimiters are opposed to the standard ones)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mikael and Kusalananda..
I got the expected result with:

```
ipconfig /all | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' | grep -A 1 'My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2$'
```

OR

```
ipconfig /all | sed -e 's/\s*$//' | grep -A 1 'My Ethernet Server Adapter B52-2$'
```

The output of `ipconfig /all` had trailing white spaces in it and hence my match did not work, with `sed` the whitespaces are removed and hence I can grep on the exact string now.
Thanks!